# Fixed point set of an isometric group action on an hyperbolic manifold

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Good morning,

I'm trying to understand the following fact, that is stated in Gromov and Thurston's paper "Pinching constants for hyperbolic manifolds" :

Let $M$ be a (at least) 3-dimensional compact oriented hyperbolic manifold, with an action of  $\mathbb{Z}_i$

by diffeomorphism. Suppose the set of fixed points of the action is a compact oriented submanifold of codimendion $2$, name it $V$, such that its homology class in $H_{n-2}(M, \mathbb{R})$ is $0$.

Mostow's Rigidity theorem ensures that $\mathbb{Z}_i$ acts by isometry.

The claim that I don't understand is : "The fixed point set of this new action is a codimension $2$ submanifold of $M$ diffeomorphic to $V$"

It is not clear in the article whether those hypothesis are sufficient or not, since the submanifold $V$ is the set of ramification of a certain covering map over an hyperbolic manifold in which the image of $V$ is totally geodesic, an the action of  $\mathbb{Z}_i$ is an action by deck transformation.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is $\mathbb{Z}_i$?

Comment: Sorry I should have precised, it's the notation used in the article for $\mathbb{Z} / i\mathbb{Z} $ 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the setup with which you are dealing: You have a smooth closed manifold $M$ and a finite cyclic branched covering $p: M\to M'$ ramified over a codimension 2 totally geodesic submanifold $V'\subset M'$, where $M'$ is hyperbolic. Let $V=p^{-1}(V')$. Furthermore, you know (from the construction) that $p: V\to V'$ is a diffeomorphism. In particular, $V$ is diffeomorphic to a closed hyperbolic manifold $V'$. Let $\beta$ denote the generator of the deck group of $p$. Now, you are trying to prove that the topological manifold $M$ does not admit a hyperbolic metric $g$. Suppose it does (smooth structure might change at this point). Then, by Mostow Rigidity theorem, $\beta: M\to M$ is homotopic to an isometry $\alpha: (M,g)\to (M,g)$. In particular, the fixed-point set $F$ of $\alpha$ is a closed hyperbolic submanifold. Note that $V$ is typically not connected, so you have to argue for each component $V_j$ of $V$. First, you note that each inclusion map $V_j\to M$ is $\pi_1$-injective (since this is the case for $V'$). Next, let's lift everything to the universal cover of $M$, which is supposed to be the hyperbolic $n$-space $H^n$, $M=H^n/\Gamma$. Then the lifts $\tilde\beta, \tilde\alpha$ can be chosen so that they agree on the sphere at infinity. The subgroup $\pi_1(V_j)\subset \Gamma$ consists of elements which commute with $\tilde\beta$. The same applies to $\pi_1(F_j)$ and to $\tilde\alpha$. Therefore, we have a natural isomorphism $\pi_1(V_j)\cong \pi_1(F_j)$. By construction, $V$ is diffeomorphic to $V'$, so $V_j$ is diffeomorphic to a hyperbolic manifold. Now, it follows from Mostow rigidity (if $dim(V)\ge 3$) or classification of surfaces (if $dim(V)=2$) that $V_j$ is diffeomorphic to $F_j$, since they are both diffeomorphic to hyperbolic manifolds with isomorphic fundamental groups.

With a bit more care, the same argument goes through if you merely assume that $M$ is homotopy-equivalent to a hyperbolic manifold.

Now, one can ask if something stronger holds: Let $M$ be a closed hyperbolic manifold and $\beta: M\to M$ be a finite order diffeomorphism. Let $\alpha: M\to M$ be an isometry homotopic to $\beta$. Is it true that fixed-point sets of $\alpha, \beta$ are diffeomorphic? 
Note that both orbifold $M/(\alpha), M/(\beta)$ are aspherical and have isomorphic fundamental groups. In dimension 3 it suffices to conclude that they are diffeomorphic. In dimensions $\ge 5$, it probably follows from some equivariant form of Farrel and Jones 
but I am not sure (I have not looked at their papers for a long time). Situations in smooth category and dimension 4 seem totally unclear.

Lastly: The paper you are reading has two constructions of negatively curved manifolds not homotopy-equivalent to locally symmetric ones. The second construction is less known since people usually get tired from reading the first one. Some details for the second construction could be found [here](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/EPR/gt.pdf). Namely, I explain why manifolds in the 2nd construction are not homotopy-equivalent to hyperbolic ones.

Comment: I have been looking at the detail of your answer and two details remain not clear to me, maybe because I don't know enough hyperbolic geometry :

_ You claim that $\Pi_1(V_j)$ consists of elements commuting with $\tilde{\beta}$, but not of THE elements commuting with $\tilde{\beta}$ right ? In that case, where does the isomorphism $\Pi_1(V_j) \simeq \Pi_1(F_j)$ comes from ?

_ Why do $F_j$ and $V_j$ have the same dimension ? Or maybe you don't use that fact, in that case if $dim(V_j) = 2$ and $dim(F_j) = 3$ how do you conclude ? 

Comment: Yes, $\pi_1(V_j)$ is exactly the set of elements commuting with $\tilde\beta$. One inclusion is clear. This shows that $\tilde\beta$ fixes pointwise a codimension 2 round sphere $S$ in the sphere at infinity. If there are extra elements which commute with $\tilde\beta$ there are two possibilities: (1) Their fixed points are not in $S$. Then $\tilde\beta$ is either identity or reverses orientation. This is not the case. (2) Their fixed points are in $S$. Then you take such element $g$ and consider a group $H$ it generates together with $F=\pi_1(V_j)$. Then $H$ is a finite extension of $F$...  

Comment: But then $\pi_1(V_j)\subset \pi_1(M')$ also admits a finite index proper extension. This contradicts the fact that $V_j'$ is embedded in $M'$. The same arguments work for $\tilde\alpha$. 

Comment: ok those last points are clear. Can I bother you with one last question ? Why is the fixed point set of $\tilde\beta$ a round sphere ? It is the accumulation set of $\tilde{V_j}$ in $\tilde{\mathbb{H}^n}$ but why can't it be degenerate ? 

Comment: The fixed point set of a Moebius transformation is always a round sphere of some dimension. In your case, this set contains the limit set of the stabilizer of $\tilde{V}_j$, which is a fundamental group of a closed hyperbolic $n-2$-manifold. Such limit set has to be topological sphere of dimension $n-3$. 

Comment: Ok, it's this last argument which is mysterious to me. I know that since $M$ can be endowed with a negatively curved metric in which $V$ is totally geodesic, the inclusion $i : \tilde V_j \longrightarrow \mathbb{H}^n $ is a quasi-isometry(for the repsective hyperbolic structures), and using Thurston's arguments, we see that we get a continuous injection $\partial_{\infty} \tilde{V_j} \longrightarrow \partial_{\infty}$ so the limit set of $\tilde{V_j}$ must be of topological dimension $n-3$. 

What is not clear to me in what you say is if some kind of analytic argument as above is ... 

Comment: hidden or if for some algebraic reason, the limit set of the stabilizer of a group isomorphic to the fundamental group of a closed hyperbolic $n-2$-manifolds has to be of dimension $n-3$ ?

Anyway thank you very much to take some time to answer my questions, this is very helpfull to me

Comment: Selim: Yes, this is a correct reasoning: each qi embedding induces continuous injection from the limit set to the sphere at infinity. This fact is one of the standard tools in geometric group theory, due to Efremovich and Tikhomirova (1964). There is an alternative argument to this, which does not need a qi embedding. Namely, Let $\Gamma$ be a Kleinian group without parabolic elements, whose  homological dimension (over ${\mathbb R})$ equals $k$. Then Hausdorff dimension of the limit set of $\Gamma$ is at least $k-1$. In our case, homological dimension is $n-2$, so H.d. of limit set is 

Comment: at least $n-3$, so each round sphere containing the limit set has dimension $\ge n-3$. The proof of the result about Hausdorff dimension is in my paper: http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/EPR/cd.pdf 
You may also want to read my survey http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/EPR/klein.pdf for further background on Kleinian groups in higher dimensions. 

  